# Составить регулярное выражение для поиска ИНН

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Требуется составить регулярное выражения для поиска ИНН в тексте.

**Первый пример возможного текста:**

> Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и
>   вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на
>   латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник
>   создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem
>   Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum ИНН 3603006880 не только
>   успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в
>   электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили
>   публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в
>   более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus
>   PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

**Второй пример возможного текста:**

> Lorem Ipsum-этотекст-"рыба",частоиспользуемыйвпечатии
>   вэб-дизайне.LoremIpsumявляется стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на
>   латиницесначалаXVIвека.Втовремянекийбезымянныйпечатник
>   создалбольшуюколлекциюразмеровиформшрифтовиспользуяLorem
>   Ipsumдляраспечаткиобразцов.LoremIpsumИНН3603006880нетолько
>   успешнопережилбеззаметныхизмененийпятьвеков,ноиперешагнулв
>   электронный дизайн.Егопопуляризациивновоевремяпослужили
>   публикациялистовLetrasetсобразцамиLoremIpsumв60-хгодахи,в
>   болеенедавнеевремя,программыэлектроннойвёрсткитипаAldus
>   PageMaker,вшаблонахкоторыхиспользуетсяLoremIpsum.

**Дополнение:**

ИНН всегда имеет фиксированную длину в 10 цифр.

Comment: Вырезать подстроку из 10 слитных цифр? `\d{10}`. или есть некие дополнительные неозвученные ограничения и признаки? ну так мы не бабки-гадалки....

Comment: @Akina Важно чтобы перед этой подстрокой было слово ИНН

Comment: Вот прям перед ней? а я в первом примере вижу ещё и пробел... или пофиг, насколько "перед"? а 100 символов - устроит? Друг мой, пожалуйста, ПРОДУМАЙТЕ ВСЕ критерии, чтобы Вас не тыкали носом в варианты, которые им соответствуют, но Вас не устроят, или наоборот...

Comment: ИНН не считается регуляркой. выдергивай все 10 и 11 цифр подряд, потом контрольное число пересчитай

Comment: @Akina для того я и указал именно 2 примера, т.к может попасться как текст где между ИНН и цифрой будет пробел, так и текст где между ними не будет пробела.

Comment: Вот что, трудно сказать, "начало строки, любое количество любых символов, затем три символа 'ИНН', после них возможен 1 пробел, затем ровно 10 цифр, затем не-цифра, затем любое количество символов, затем конец строки, необходимо получить группу из 10 цифр"? Вот это - уже алгоритм.

Comment: Попробуй `/^(.*ИНН ?)(\d{10})(\D.*)$/\2/gm` ([fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/vN1DOV/2)) - может, устроит?

Comment: @Akina не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
txt = 'Ipsum ИНН 3603006880 не толькоIpsumИНН5503006990'
inn_lst = re.findall('ИНН\x20*(\d{10})', txt)
```

**inn_lst:**

```
['3603006880', '5503006990']
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, как работает данное регулярное выражение?

Comment: ИНН - ну, это понятно;
\x20* - тут квантор - * говорит что пробел \x20 может быть 0 и больше раз;
\d{10} - 10 цифр;
() - ну и скобки говорят что на вытащить регуляркой;